# PayPal 3D-secure authentication Exception

Tags: web-applications, paypal, payment-gateway

I have integrated ***PayPal*** in my web application for transaction.When I try to ***make transaction*** I get the following ***error from paypal*** result of which transaction gets failed.

***"Transaction is not compliant due to missing or invalid 3D-secure authentication values"***

and the respective ***Error Code is 12000.***

When I tried to find the solution for this i came across ***Check ECI, ECI3DS,CAVV, XID fields.*** .But I have no idea what these fileds means .Can anyone help to find where I am going wrong, Thanks.

The API i making use of is doDirectPaymwent

Comment: Please include the API call you're sending (minus the API credentials).

Comment: @Robert : i get the exception when the amount to be transfered is 120

Comment: Then it's for Sandbox I'm assuming? In https://developer.paypal.com/, go to 'Test accounts' and turn 'Negative review' off.

Comment: @Robert : ya its Sandbox. After disabling 'Negative review' I am not getting such error .THANKS Robert. But may I know the reason for such error and will such error arise when I integrate with the **LIVE server of PAYPAL** ?

Comment: Negative review is Sandbox-specific functionality which lets you trigger specific error responses by sending a specific AMT (or in this case of Express Checkout), a specific TOKEN. For example, AMT=104.67 will trigger error code 10467 to be returned, while AMT=120.00 will return error code 12000. This is to let you test error conditions in the Sandbox environment. This won't occur on the Live environment.

Comment: @Robert You are my favorite person today!